What would be a good translation for Gen 2:12-14, or directly from the Hebrew text?
I can't understand these verses from Genesis of chapter 2. Specifically, in 2:12 about the two elements, 2:13 about the land that this river encircles, and 2:14 about whether Tigris was going, at those days, before or east of the Assyrians.
The Septuagint may be saying something different from the English translations which translate the Hebrew; e.g. in 2:12 they translates as bdellium and onyx stone. The Septuagint says "carbon" and "the green stone". "Carbon" means the lighted coal (generally, when it has the colour of fire), and by extension, in Greek (the "ἄνθραξ"), it also means the red gemstone; I do not know whether it has any connection with the bdellium. Of the green stone they mention, I know nothing.
Questions

Do you think it should be translated as "bdellium" and "onyx stone"?

What city was the Gihon River encircling?

Was the river Tigris going east of the Assyrians, or before the Assyrians?


Any suggestions/opinion will be appreciated!

In Numbers 11:7, MT has bdellium to describe colour of manna; LXX translated it as krystallos, and for MT entry  Gesenius' Lexicon suggests two main versions - light-yellow tree resin or pearls. The "green stone" was a common name for onyx among people who were into minerals, I don't remember from where I know that, sapphire was called in the same manner as the "blue stone" in old days. If I remember correctly, there are limited species of minerals that can be found on surface, that's why such naming had came up.

in Psalm 148:8 krystallos used to depict english-bible 'snow', and context is so straight that in no way it can be translated as red or fire anything (fire explicitly in the verse). That's very interesting why LXX used anthrax specifically in that place, - yes, it's shiny, but krystallos too.

@RaySolva Thank you very much for these informations! Are useful.

Young's Literal Translation might shed more light.

10 And a river is going out from Eden to water the garden, and from thence it is parted, and hath become four chief [rivers];


11 the name of the one [is] Pison, it [is] that which is surrounding the whole land of the Havilah where the gold [is],


12 and the gold of that land [is] good, there [is] the bdolach and the shoham stone;


13 and the name of the second river [is] Gibon, it [is] that which is surrounding the whole land of Cush;


14 and the name of the third river [is] Hiddekel, it [is] that which is going east of Asshur; and the fourth river is Phrat.  (Gen. 2:10-14, YLT)

The second river Gihon or Gibon was circling the whole land of Cush, which may have been the ancient land west of the Nile.  Clark's Commentary on Gen. 2:10, 12 offers:

The most probable account of its situation is that given by Hadrian Reland. He supposes it to have been in Armenia, near the sources of the great rivers Euphrates, Tigris, Phasis, and Araxes. He thinks Pison was the Phasis, a river of Colchis, emptying itself into the Euxine Sea, where there is a city called Chabala, the pronunciation of which is nearly the same with that of Havilah, or חוילה Chavilah, according to the Hebrew, the ו vau being changed in Greek to beta β. This country was famous for gold, whence the fable of the Golden Fleece, attempted to be carried away from that country by the heroes of Greece. The Gihon he thinks to be the Araxes, which runs into the Caspian Sea, both the words having the same signification, viz., a rapid motion. The land of Cush, washed by the river, he supposes to be the country of the Cussaei of the ancients. The Hiddekel all agree to be the Tigris, and the other river Phrat, or פרת Perath, to be the Euphrates. All these rivers rise in the same tract of mountainous country, though they do not arise from one head.   ....  There is bdellium (בדלח bedolach) and the onyx stone, אבן השהם eben hashshoham.] Bochart thinks that the bedolach or bdellium means the pearl-oyster; and shoham is generally understood to mean the onyx, or species of agate, a precious stone which has its name from ονυξ a man's nail, to the colour of which it nearly approaches. It is impossible to say what is the precise meaning of the original words; and at this distance of time and place it is of little consequence.  (Clarke's)

Keil and Delitzsch Commentary at Biblehub.com has a good discussion of the elements and the rivers, but says that the Cush in Gen. 2 was an earlier land different from that of the later Arabian.

The Gihon (from גּוּח to break forth) is the Araxes, which rises in the neighbourhood of the Euphrates, flows from west to east, joins the Cyrus, and falls with it into the Caspian Sea. The name corresponds to the Arabic Jaihun, a name given by the Arabians and Persians to several large rivers. The land of Cush cannot, of course, be the later Cush, or Ethiopia, but must be connected with the Asiatic Κοσσαία, which reached to the Caucasus, and to which the Jews (of Shirwan) still give this name. But even though these four streams do not now spring from one source, but on the contrary their sources are separated by mountain ranges, this fact does not prove that the narrative before us is a myth. Along with or since the disappearance of paradise, that part of the earth may have undergone such changes that the precise locality can no longer be determined with certainty.  (Biblehub)

There is much speculation, and differing opinions on these stones and rivers.  It is interesting to research, but we may never know for sure what they are.

Thank you so much for this information! +1
